# $F_{\sigma}$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, general-topology

Suppose $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ is of type $F_{\sigma}$. That is $C$ can be written as the union of $F_{n}$'s where each $F_{n}$'s are closed. Then can we prove that each point of $C$ is a point of discontinuity for some $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I refered this link on wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function and in the follow up subsection they given this result. I would like somebody to explain it more precisely.

Comment: Please fix the link.

Comment: You need to say something more if you want an interesting problem. Maybe you want the $F_n$'s to be small in some sense?

Comment: @Kenny TM: Thanks for fixing the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like the construction mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165/does-the-continuous-locus-of-a-function-have-any-nice-properties/174#174).

Answer (score 1):

One can also see this article, "S.S.Kim, Amer.Math.Monthly 106 (1999), 258-259".