# Does there exist such a function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Can we find a function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ that is continuous only at the points $ 1,2,\ldots,100 $?

Comment: Can you find a function continuous only at $0$?

Comment: $f(x)=\sqrt{-|x|}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructing Continuous functions at given points](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7821/constructing-continuous-functions-at-given-points)

Comment: Wait that's not continuous, thought he meant exist, my bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $$f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{100}(x-i)1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$$ where $1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $0$ otherwise. Can you show that it has the desired properties?

Comment: how can i show that it is contiuous?

Comment: give me some hint to prove this function is continuous.

Comment: If $f \to 0$ as $x \to a$ and $g$ is bounded, then $f g \to 0$ as $x \to a$. This shows continuity at $x=1,2,\ldots,100$. Can you finish the proof by showing the function isn't continuous anywhere else?

Comment: Can we draw the graph of this function?

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi No we can't. It is discontinuous at all but 100 points. Functions that you can draw well are typically continuous (differentiable) at all but finitely many points.

Comment: i understant in the case of rationals f(a) exists and limit f is exists as x tends to a and both are same.it will be zero.In the case of irrational which limit is not exists?

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi I don't quite understand what you are asking. The function is continuous at $x=1,2,\ldots,100$ and discontinuous at all other points. Neither the left nor right limits exist at any point besides $x=1,2,\ldots,100$.

Comment: i m thinking about the discontinuity points.

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi I have answered every question you asked at all points, including discontinuity points.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Consider the function
$$f(x) = x\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$$
where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of $A$. Prove that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous only in $0$ and elaborate on the concept.