# Functions that are continuous only at two points?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I need to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous only at two points, but discontinuous everywhere else.

How on earth would I go about doing this? I can't think of **any** function like this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've seen examples including the indicator function for rationals. Is this the only method of finding such functions?

Comment: Please See this link : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7821/constructing-continuous-functions-at-given-points

Comment: Yes, I've made an edit to make sure this question is **not** a duplicate.

Comment: Not about duplicate..The link seemed very good to me,that's why I suggeseted

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to thank you for the link, it was helpful! I just wanted to ensure and stress that this wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: Don't be sorry.I got your point.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Think of something like
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
x & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R-Q}\\
\end{cases}
$$
This is only continuous at two points, namely where $x^2=x$.

Comment: very nice! And it can be extended easily to any $n$ by using polynomials of degree $n$ (checking that there are different roots, but still!)

Answer (score 20):

The following function is a standard example of a function that is continuous at one point only:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x &: x \in \Bbb Q \\
0 &: \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

Show that this is indeed the case. Can you think of a way to modify it so that it's continuous at two points? Hint:

> Instead of $x$ in the first case, consider the polynomial $(x - x_0)(x - x_1)$.

This can be generalized to construct a function that is continuous at a finite set of points only.

Answer (score 8):

What about 
$$
  f(x)
= \begin{cases}
  x(1-x) & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
  0   & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \\
  \end{cases}?
$$

Answer (score 6):

General answer. If you have $a(x)$ and $c(x)$ continuous and $b(x)$ nowhere continuous, then
$$a(x)\cdot b(x) + c(x)$$
is continuous at $x$, *iff* $a(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible to use something other than the rational indicator function to define these functions.  Specifically, take $S$ to be a set define the function $I_S$ by

$$I_S(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & x \in S\\ 0 & x \not\in S\end{array}\right.$$

This function is called the *indicator function* of $S$.  Now, let $S$ be a [dense subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $S^C$ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$.  (For example, we could take $S$ to be the set of all rational numbers with terminating decimal expansions.) Then, the function

$$f(x) = x^2I_S(x) + x(1-I_{S}(x))$$

is continuous at only $x=0$ and $x=1.$