# Continuous at rationals implies continous at all real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Consider a real valued function $f$ continuous at all rational numbers, and perhaps at some other points. Is it necessary that $f$ be continuous on the entire real line?

My impression is that yes, $f$ must be continuous on the entire real line:

Fix a point $x$ on the real line. Given a fixed $\epsilon' > 0$, I want to show that for some $\beta > 0$ we have: $f(N_\beta(x)) \subseteq N_{\epsilon'}(f(x))$.

Since continuity at each rational $q$ implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that $f(N_\alpha(q)) \subseteq N_{\epsilon}(f(q))$ and since we can choose a $q$ arbitrarily close to $x$, then we have that the desired claim holds.

I could use some feedback on my reasoning.

Comment: It is certainly not true that a function that is continuous at all rationals must be continuous everywhere: just take the function whose value is $0$ everywhere except at $\pi$, and with value $1$ at $\pi$. This function is continuous at all $x\neq \pi$, and in particular at all rationals. Run your reasoning through this example, with $x=\pi$, to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: What *is* true is that a function cannot be continuous at *exactly* the rationals and nowhere else. Because it is known that the set of discontinuities of a function must be a countable union of closed sets. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7825/742) for examples of functions with a variety of sets of points of discontinuity.